# What is the name of this yellow bumble bee that I photographed in New York City?

Tags: botany, species-identification

Does anybody know the name of this bumblebee? (For categorization on Wikipedia Commons: [1](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Flower-3.jpg) and [2](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Flower-7.jpg))

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just to help prevent other non-native English speakers make the same common mistake, you cannot say “How is something called” in English (unlike French, German and most other Germanic or Romance languages). It is “What is it called”. However, in changing the title I used what I considered a more suitable construction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a Brown-belted Bumble Bee (*Bombus griseocollis*).

[image]

Details: http://bugguide.net/node/view/3538